# Install node modules error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have `test` directory and `package.json` file in it:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": { 
    "hem": "~0.1.6",
  }
}
```

When i try to execute `node install` i get following error:

```
module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/shk/test/install'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Umm, it's `npm install` not `node install`. `node` is used to execute a JavaScript file. `npm` is used to run tasks related to package/module management.